# get enum class values to dropdown list

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

I have an enum class and I want to get values of enum class into the dropdown list. The following code shows how I tried to do it. (I just add enum values as values of options in select). but I want to get data from enum class as the dropdown item.

-Enum class

```
public enum Status implements BaseEnum {
    PENDING(0, "PENDING"), PROCESS(1, "PROCESS"), REJECT(2, "REJECT"));

    private int code;

    private String name;

    private Status(int code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }
      public int getCode() {
        return code;
      }

      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }

private static final Map<Integer, Status> LOOKUP = new HashMap<Integer, Status>();

    static {
        for (Status status: EnumSet.allOf(Status.class)) {
            LOOKUP.put(status.getCode(), status);
        }
    }

    public static Status fromCode(int code) {
        return LOOKUP.get(code);
    }

}
```

-Dropdown list

```
<select class="form-control" id="status">
        <option value="${statusDTO.status}">${statusDTO.status}</option>
        <option value="PENDING">PENDING</option>
        <option value="PROCESS">PROCESS</option>
        <option value="REJECT">REJECT</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **show all values** in your `Status` enum in dropdown list, you can do as follows:

```html
<select id="status" name="status">
    <option th:each="status : ${T(com.stackoverflow.enums.Status).values()}" 
        th:value="${status}" th:text="${status}"></option>
</select>
```

You can do as follows to show a **different value**:

```html
<select id="status" name="status">
    <option th:each="status : ${T(com.stackoverflow.enums.Status).values()}" 
        th:value="${status}" th:text="${status.name}"></option>
</select>
```

If you want to **highlight** your choice, you can use if statement:

```html
<select id="status" name="status">
    <option 
        th:each="status : ${T(com.stackoverflow.enums.Status).values()}" 
        th:value="${status}" th:text="${status.name}" 
        th:selected="${status == statusDTO.status}"></option>
</select>
```

You can reproduce these examples, you can review [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-enums) for different enum scenarios or [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-select-option) for different select scenarios.

Comment: what is the T is this expresion "${T(com.stackoverflow.enums.Status).values()}"?

Comment: This is operator to access a class level (static) field or method, the part of `SpEL (Spring Expression Language)`. See types section (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions) for more information.